# sql server 2008 r2 top (1) to update date not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with two colums (startTime, endTime) , those are from dataTime type.

when I insert a row in this table I want to update previous data in this table like this:

```
update endTime in the row which has most recent (max) startTime
```

I worked (like another thread tell me) like this:

```
BEGIN
    ;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by startTime desc) RNum
    from Order_Status
    where OrderID=@orderID
    )
    update top(1) T set endTime=@startTime
    END
```

but it seems like it updates the small (most old) not most recent.

what is the right please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually applying the ordering from the `ROW_NUMBER` method, you want something like this:

```
BEGIN
 ;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by startTime desc) RNum
    from Order_Status
    where OrderID=@orderID
  )
  update T set endTime=@startTime
  from (select top 1 * from T order by RNum ASC) T
END
```

Or to be a bit neater, this should work (untested):

```
BEGIN
 ;with T as(
    select top 1 *
    from Order_Status
    where OrderID=@orderID
    order by startTime desc
  )
  update T set endTime=@startTime
END
```

Comment: Your first needs to order ascending on RNum since startTime is ordered descending. Still... +1 for the second solution :).

Comment: Thanks @Mikael, updated the ordering in the first one so it should be right for either

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Order_Status
SET endTime=@startTime
WHERE startTime = (SELECT MAX(StartTime) FROM Order_Status where OrderID=@orderID)
AND OrderID=@orderID
```